# Как сохранить текст с тегами в SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, qt, база-данных, sql

Необходимо создать такую базу данных, которая позволяла бы хранить текст, помечая его тегами. Поглив по форумам нашел один из [вариантов](http://www.askdev.ru/databases/705/Как-правильно-хранить-теги-контента-в-базе), где предлагается создать две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "content" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "content" text,
  PRIMARY KEY  ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "content_tag" (
  "id_content" int NOT NULL,
  "tag_value" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY "id_content_tag" ("id_content","tag_value"),
  CONSTRAINT "content_tag_ibfk_1" FOREIGN KEY ("id_content") REFERENCES "content" ("id"),
);
```

Первая таблица создалась, а вторая c внешними ключами нет?

> Ошибка: Kernel error: near "KEY":
> syntax error

На сколько я понял ошибка в строке:

```
UNIQUE KEY "id_content_tag" ("id_content","tag_value")
```

1) Как создать вторую таблицу?

2) И как выглядить запрос на сохранения данных при таком структуре базы? К примеру, как мне добавить текст: **"boos::filesystem"** с двумя тегами ***c++*** и ***boost***?

Comment: Лучше использовать такую структуру: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O67tv.jpg 
вязто тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387006/getting-tags-for-content-from-second-table-in-one-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
CREATE TABLE "content_tag" (
  "id_content" int NOT NULL,
  "tag_value" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "id_content_tag" UNIQUE ("id_content","tag_value"),
  CONSTRAINT "content_tag_ibfk_1" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("id_content") REFERENCES "content" ("id")
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9ce2c/4)

ЗЫ Надеюсь, ваш sqlite поддерживает foreign keys ([FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433250/foreign-key-constraint-doesnt-work))
ЗЗЫ про структуру @huffman прав, лучше иметь развязочную таблицу.